# Best GUI Approach with Java for a Monopoly Board Game

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I have a project to create a multi-player monopoly game I have a pretty good idea how to implement it but until now I had practically no experience with GUIs. What I want to do is I want the board to look pretty realistic so my main concerns are is SWING capable of providing me with:

a) clickable squares (supporting right click menus) and a background image

b) moving pieces (a "float from one square to another" animation would be nice) which would
stay over a square and would support right click menus

c) Pop up menus with a radio button.

Basically my main concern is the floating piece animation and the rolling dice animation (ok the last one is not so important).

If I can't do that with SWING can I do that with QT?

Comment: I believe that swing is a best choice for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Swing library should be fine to use. It contains all of the GUI components you mention plus more.

When you mention animation, with pieces floating from one square to another, if they are going to be overlapping, passing through, or landing on some of your GUI components (like, if you plan on having the GUI components as part of the gameboard, as opposed to a side menu of game options), then I might suggest looking into rendering Swing with your game's graphics at the same time, so the graphics can appear on top or on bottom of whatever components you have when needed.

You can find a tutorial on setting up a frame with game like graphics while rendering Swing at the same time here (the method in the tutorial uses active rendering, which is preferable when wanting smooth time based animations, such as the dice roll you want):

http://www.jamesgames.org/resources/double_buffer/double_buffering_and_active_rendering.html

[image: Swing embedded with the game's graphics/board etc]
<sub>(source: [jamesgames.org](http://jamesgames.org/resources/double_buffer/activecircles.png))</sub>

Answer (score 7):

Yes, you can do all of those with Swing. You can use AWT too if you choose.

I wrote a simple chess game in Java. Here is the link: http://www.kanersan.com/myfiles/ChessSource.zip

It has a simple GUI.

Enjoy.

Comment: Same as above :-) I would love to see you code in action...can you share the images as well? It's choking at images as of now.

Comment: Sure thing, the images are here: http://www.kanersan.com/myfiles/Chess.zip as well as the .jar file. Note that this .jar is newer than the code, but the code should be enough for basic Graphics action. Enjoy

Comment: +1 for free game. How do I make my men move when I run the jar?

Comment: You just click on pieces and move them. If you're running it on mac though there might be a problem. I think this is because mac's screen coordinates are inverted (compared to windows). White starts first.

Comment: I'm running Windows 7 Professional 64bit and can't get my men to move; dragging, clicking, right-clicking/dragging, both mouse buttons at the same time - none of these worked for me when running the jar. Tried starting a new game, no effect.

Answer (score 4):

You can easily do that in SWING using `Graphics2D` All what you need is to understand how to paint some graphics and animate them. This [tutorial](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/painting/) should be of a good help to you.